# Is there a way to delete or update Whatsapp message sent by the User to Twilio Bot?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm creating a chatbot on WhatsApp that requires Users authentication, so the bot would be asking for Users credentials and do the validation from our server-side. So I want to self-destruct the Users password(delete or update to XXXXXX) for security purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can either [delete a message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#delete-a-message-resource) or [update it to remove the body](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#update-a-message-resource) that is stored in Twilio. I wrote a blog post about [how to delete or redact messages as they arrive in Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/01/redact-delete-sms-messages-node-js.html), which might be of help. It is about SMS, but WhatsApp messages are treated the same.

Note, I don't think you can update the message that the user sent to you from WhatsApp, just the representation of it within Twilio.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @philnash. You are right, we cannot delete User message on his WhatsApp, at least I can delete the Users message in Twilio with your approach.

Comment: Hi @philnash, as of 2021 is this still expected behaviour? Deleting a message using MessageResource only removes it from twilio, not whatsapp? On phone the message is still there just not in twilio.

Comment: That is correct @KJN. Check the WhatsApp API itself, there is no endpoint for deleting a message: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages

Comment: I see, guess for now most applications just won't enable deletions. Even the whatsapp delete confirmation message for business chats shows it won't delete for "Everyone", just for the user. Thank you for your quick reply.